# Oracle set schema password never expire

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the following query to check the status on the PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME field from dba_profiles table.

How I ensured that the password never expires was to do this. Is the alter profile query correct?

```
ALTER PROFILE my_profile LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;

select du.USERNAME,du.profile, dp.LIMIT
from dba_users du 
left outer join dba_profiles dp on dp.PROFILE = du.PROFILE
where du.USERNAME = 'SYSTEM' and resource_name LIKE 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alter profile query is correct. The password for the profile `my_profile` never expires due to password life time. You need to assign the profile `my_profile` to the user `system` with `alter user system profile my_profile;`